Design pattern help needed - reusable dialog
I've got a table of users.  For each user I'd like the ability to popup a dialog to be able to edit the data for the user.  The basic structure currently looks like:
{
  header: 'Edit User',
  cell: (cell) => {
    return (
      <>
        <SimpleFormDialog dialogOpen={open}
                          onClose={handleClose}
                          firstName={cell.row.original.firstName}
                          lastName={cell.row.original.lastName}
                          email={cell.row.original.email}
                          enabled={cell.row.original.enabled}
        />
        <IconButton aria-label="edit">
          <EditOutlined onClick={handleClickOpen} />
        </IconButton>
      </>
    );
  }
},

The SimpleFormDialog looks like:
const SimpleFormDialog = ({ onClose, dialogOpen, firstName, lastName, email, enabled }:
                            { onClose: () => void;
                              dialogOpen: boolean;
                              firstName?: string;
                              lastName?: string;
                              email?: string;
                              enabled?: boolean;
                            }) => {

  const handleClose = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog

 ...

The challenge I'm having is that my SimpleFormDialog is now sharing the boolean "open" across all instances.  In the process, there are inconsistencies in opening.  Additionally, only information for the last user is populated into the dialog.
My ReactJS with MUI experience is incredibly weak at best.  In my way of thinking the button onClick should do something equivalent to a new Dialog(parameters) and have that take care of everything.  I'm struggling to think in the proper way to handle this.  I started to go down the path of an array of booleans for open but quickly got myself wrapped around the axle on that.
For reference, I've tried material-ui-confirm but I need a form and that library seems most suited for "Are you sure" types of dialogs.
Can someone point me in the right direction?  Multiple other programming languages and environments have not beaten me but ReactJS / Typescript are sure doing a job on me.

What you're likely looking for is the React Provider Pattern.
there is a good example in this npm package ad it has the provider and hook already written for you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-modal-provider

import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import ModalProvider, { useModal } from 'mui-modal-provider';
import Dialog, { DialogProps } from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

interface SimpleDialogProps extends DialogProps {
  title: string,
};

// Create the dialog you want to use
const SimpleDialog: React.FC<SimpleDialogProps> = ({ title, ...props }) => (
  <Dialog {...props}>
    <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
  </Dialog>
);

// Use modal hook and show the dialog
const App = () => {
  const { showModal } = useModal();

  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      onClick={() => showModal(SimpleDialog, { title: 'Simple Dialog' })}
      color="primary"
    >
      simple dialog
    </Button>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

// Wrap the app with modal provider
root.render(
  <ModalProvider>
    <App />
  </ModalProvider>
);



The Gist is to wrap the React Application in a provider, then you can call in a modal/component from anywhere in the app without having to create and configure new instances in every component as well as being able to manage the state of the one instance globally.
learn more about useContext and Providers
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html
https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

You rock - I was making it far too difficult.  Thanks!
